# Change Toggle Switch Color

Tags: iphone, ios, toggle

I'm using this code to change the color of a Toggle Switch, when it is in "ON" mode,

```
toggleSwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
```

Is there any method that I can change the color when the switch is in "off" mode?
Because when it in "off" mode, its become transparent.

Edited:

```
toggleSwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
            toggleSwitch.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
            toggleSwitch.thumbTintColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

also, didn't work . When the Switch is "off" always it's get transparent in the inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the toggleSwitch when you toggle it on and off with the following code.

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    if(sender.isOn) {
        sender.onTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        sender.thumbTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    } else {
        sender.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tintColor
```

The color used to tint the appearance when the switch is disabled.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor
```

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/tintColor)

Comment: I want to know, how to apply the color when the switch is in "Off" mode?

Comment: and when in off state it shows in a single color ,You want to change that?But it is the default behavior of switch.Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, but didn't work.I try,

toggleSwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
                toggleSwitch.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
                toggleSwitch.thumbTintColor=[UIColor redColor];`

Answer (score 0):

set tintColor of toggleSwitch when switch is off.

and you can detect switch state

```
if(toggleSwitch.isOn]))
```

Comment: What is the method to set the "Off" colour?

Comment: if(![toggleSwitch.isOn]))

Answer (score 0):

Though super late to the party, for future users...

XCode way to do it is Set `on tint` and `tint`.

Refer Image:

[image: On tint]